# starting hadoop process using start-all.sh runs into issues

Tags: hadoop

i am using redhat linux 4.1.2 When i try to start hadoop using the below command it asks for root@localhost password. I don't understand what password to enter here.

> sreenath@sreenath-pc# sudo -i [root@sreenath-pc hadoop-1.1.1]#
>   bin/start-all.sh Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
>
> starting namenode, logging to
>   /opt/hadoop-1.1.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-namenode-sreenath-pc
>   .out root@localhost's password: root@localhost's password: localhost:
>   Permission denied, please try again.
>
> [1]+  Stopped                 bin/start-all.sh

I have given the current user "sreenath" password

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your SSH isn't setup properly

Setup passphraseless ssh

Now check that you can ssh to the localhost without a passphrase:

```
$ ssh localhost
```

If you cannot ssh to localhost without a passphrase, execute the
following commands:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Execution

Format a new distributed-filesystem:

```
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Start The hadoop daemons:

```
$ bin/start-all.sh
```

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.17.0/quickstart.html#Setup+passphraseless

or

Refer [Micheal Noll's link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) for running Hadoop on your machine.

Comment: this worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: i was having an rsa which i dont want to change. but this idea helped me resolve the issue perfectly.

Comment: this solution is good but not enough. check that security on your remote login in system preferences has yourself and admin added.

Answer (score 0):

you can go [here](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-setup-and-configure-ssh-on-ubuntu.html) to see how ssh can be configured and [here](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-configure-hadoop.html) to see how Hadoop can be configured

HTH