# HADOOP - Permission denied executing start-all.sh

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to install Hadoop on my laptop. I followed this guide: https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

When I try to run start-all.sh I get this:

```
vava@vava-ThinkPad:/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.1/sbin$ bash start-all.sh
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as vava in 10 seconds.

WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
pdsh@vava-ThinkPad: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
Starting datanodes
pdsh@vava-ThinkPad: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [vava-ThinkPad]
pdsh@vava-ThinkPad: vava-ThinkPad: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
Starting resourcemanager
resourcemanager is running as process 3748.  Stop it first.
Starting nodemanagers
pdsh@vava-ThinkPad: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
```

I tried to follow this questions but nothing changed:

[starting hadoop process using start-all.sh runs into issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909568/starting-hadoop-process-using-start-all-sh-runs-into-issues)

[Hadoop permission issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412763/hadoop-permission-issue)

**EDIT :**
After I tried all the options, the only one that seems to work is `export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh`.
Now the problem is with namenode and datanode. It doesn't start properly:

```
vava@vava-ThinkPad:/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.1$ sbin/start-all.sh
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as vava in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
pdsh@vava-ThinkPad: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 1
Starting datanodes
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 10937
pdsh@vava-ThinkPad: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 1
Starting secondary namenodes [vava-ThinkPad]
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
```

Comment: Did you try with sudo? sudo start-all.sh

Comment: If you `ssh localhost`, does it work without a password prompt? Secondly, that tutorial is super old. Please, please follow the official Hadoop documentation for your specific version

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh yes, nothing changed.

Comment: According to this, whatever configurations you took from that tutorial are not going to work with Hadoop3, as I mentioned before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283634/localhost-error-cannot-set-priority-of-datanode-process-32156

Answer (score 1):

### I would check:

- `export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh` in your terminal
- Local Firewall settings
- Running the command as root: `sudo /usr/local/hadoop-3.1.1/sbin$ bash start-all.sh`
- `chmod -R 755 /usr/local/hadoop-3.1.1`

### For your additional question:

- Set `JAVA_HOME` in `hadoop-env.sh` and make sure all other options are correct in this file
- Change your user, `Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as
  vava in 10 seconds.` **"`vava`"** Is wrong, try `su -l hdfs` then run the script

Comment: 'export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh' seems to work, but now I have a problem with datanode and namenode. I edited the original question.
Thank @Petro for having solved the main problem.

Comment: Change your user: `Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as vava in 10 seconds.` try `su -l hdfs` then run the script...see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file

```
/etc/pdsh/rcmd_default
```

write ”ssh“ to it, and then save&quit. Make sure you enter a return character and start a new line, otherwise SSH exit with code 1 will be prompted

```
echo "ssh" > /etc/pdsh/rcmd_default
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case you need to make sure to copy the RSA to the current localhost

```
ssh-copy-id -i /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop@localhost
```

Assuming you are logged in to the node-master with "hadoop"